# Import extrenal SWF to FLA file and align it in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a project FLA and i am trying to import to stage one external SWF. The code that i am using to import SWF is:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myswf.swf");

var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.load(request);

addChild(loader);
```

When i import it, the SWF isn't align. Is there any code compatible with my code, to center it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myswf.swf");

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoadComplete); 
loader.load(request);

function onSWFLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var loadedSWF:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target.content);

    loadedSWF.x = 150; // x position on stage
    loadedSWF.y = 200; // y position on stage

    addChild(loadedSWF);
}
```

Comment: typeError #1034: fail of coercion type: is not possible to convert flash display:: AVM1Movie@31667e21 flash.display.Movieclip.                   i am getting this error any ideas?